# AWS Query attribute not working as expected

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am trying to filter the output using --query option in aws cli. But its not working as expected.

For example, on using this command

```
 aws cloudtrail lookup-events --lookup-attributes AttributeKey=ResourceName,AttributeValue=ccp-sample --region us-west-2 --query 'Events[0].CloudTrailEvent'
```

I get this output

```
"{\"eventVersion\":\"1.03\",\"userIdentity\":{\"type\":\"IAMUser\",\"principalId\":\"AIDAIIR6LX4HJMES3LKSO\",\"arn\":\"arn:aws:iam::198282748449:user/yash\",\"accountId\":\"198282748449\",\"accessKeyId\":\"ASIAIT27FOX6LO5AUMCA\",\"userName\":\"yash\",\"sessionContext\":{\"attributes\":{\"mfaAuthenticated\":\"true\",\"creationDate\":\"2016-07-26T12:24:46Z\"}},\"invokedBy\":\"signin.amazonaws.com\"},\"eventTime\":\"2016-07-26T12:55:37Z\",\"eventSource\":\"s3.amazonaws.com\",\"eventName\":\"DeleteBucket\",\"awsRegion\":\"us-west-2\",\"sourceIPAddress\":\"AWS Internal\",\"userAgent\":\"signin.amazonaws.com\",\"requestParameters\":{\"bucketName\":\"ccp-sample\"},\"responseElements\":null,\"requestID\":\"85D3C0AD43A4FB15\",\"eventID\":\"a525764b-0a9e-435d-ae1e-252879da9812\",\"eventType\":\"AwsApiCall\",\"recipientAccountId\":\"198282748449\"}"
```

But when i tried to get the eventTime with something like this

```
aws cloudtrail lookup-events --lookup-attributes AttributeKey=ResourceName,AttributeValue=ccp-sample --region us-west-2 --query 'Events[0].CloudTrailEvent.eventTime'
```

I am getting null. I don't know where i am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which event time you are talking about.

```
aws cloudtrail lookup-events --lookup-attributes AttributeKey=ResourceName,AttributeValue=ccp-sample --region us-west-2 --query 'Events[0].EventTime'
```

You can`t inspect the CloudTrailEvent field with the query parameter. It's only a String with JSON, but the CLI does not know about that.